# Loop through XML result (a list) getting more details from another XML request

Tags: xml, rest, powershell

OK I have manage to cobble together 2 XML requests that return the info I would like to ultimately put into a CSV. I need some help to loop one over the other, I have tried various For Each loops etc. but I just don't seem to get it to work. I'm not sure if there is a better / more efficient way to make the request, any suggestions welcome.

```
$username = "abc"
$password = "mypassword"
$encoded =  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username+":"+$password ))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic " + $encoded}

$ConnectionURI = "https://api.myisp.net/xml/stable/ListConnections.php?liveorceased=live&fields=Customer Ref"
$GetConnections = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ConnectionURI -Headers $headers
$ConnectionList = $GetConnections.ResponseBlock.Response.OperationResponse.ADSLAccount
$ConDetailsURI = "https://api.myisp.net/xml/stable/AdslAccount.php?ref=" + $Connections

$details = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ConDetailsURI -Headers $headers
$details.ResponseBlock.Response.OperationResponse.ADSLAccount |
    Select OurRef, Telephone, NAT, IPAddress, FullUsername, Status, CBUK,
           Downstream, Upstream
```

`$ConnectionList` returns the following:

```
CustomerRef
-----------
ADSL123456
ADSL789101
ADSL000001
ADSL007111
ADSL111111
ADSL222222
ADSL333333
ADSL444444
ADSL555555
ADSL666666
ADSL777777
ADSL888888
ADSL999999
```

Which I would like to request the details for from `https://api.myisp.net/xml/stable/AdslAccount.php?ref=" + $ConnectionList`.

An example of the `$details` returned:

```
OurRef       : ADSL123456 
Telephone    : 0123456789 
NAT          : Y 
IPAddress    : 70.1.2.3 
FullUsername : 0123456789@vmyisp.net 
Status       : Installed 
CBUK         : BBEU21234561 
Downstream   : 80Mbit/s 
Upstream     : 20Mbit/s
```

Comment: Unless the server accepts multiple references you need to invoke the URI for each reference in a loop.

Comment: Please do not edit tags into the subject of your question.